# Can't connect to 2g or 3g with my Ubuntu phone (Aquaris E5)

Tags: phone, 3g, aquaris

I just bought a Ubuntu phone (Aquaris E5) the only problem is that I can't connect to my 2g or 3g, but the wifi works fine. BTW I live in Sweden so it should be fine and what carrier should I use?

Comment: Can you edit in more details about your problem? E.g, is the SIM card detected, does it say you have a *network* connection (can you send/receive calls/texts?) or just not a *data* connection?

Comment: What happens after a hard reset/switching to airplane mode?

Comment: I solved the problem, It was my company who needed to change some settings remotly. So if you have the same problem just contact the phone operators.